# TypeError: cur is undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, smooth-scrolling

I am trying to implement smooth scroll on a webpage
this is what i did:

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
 $('body').sectionScroll();
  $(function(){
    $(".element").typed({
      strings: ["Creativity", "Uniqueness", "prime Innovation"],
      // Optionally use an HTML element to grab strings from (must wrap each string in a <p>)
      stringsElement: null,
      // typing speed
      typeSpeed: 1,
      // time before typing starts
      startDelay: 0,
      // backspacing speed
      backSpeed: 0,
      // time before backspacing
      backDelay: 500,
      // loop
      loop: true,
      // false = infinite
      loopCount: false,
      // show cursor
      showCursor: true,
      // character for cursor
      cursorChar: "|"
    });
    $('a[href*=#]:not([href=#])').click(function() {
    if (location.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') == this.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') 
     || location.hostname == this.hostname) { 
     var target = $(this.hash);
     target = target.length ? target : $('[name=' + this.hash.slice(1) +']');
      if (target.length) {
         $('html,body').animate({
             scrollTop: target.offset().top
        }, 1000);
            return false;
     }
    }
  });
  });
});
```

and when I run the pagein browser, all my javascript doesnt seem to work. I checked the console and this is error I got:

> TypeError: cur is undefined

pade demo at http://cinsol.stamplayapp.com

Comment: In your script cur is returning nil, so change line n 82 in your script to this.
`if (!cur == undefined || !cur == null || !cur == []) 
{
 var id = cur[0] ? cur[0].id : '';
}`

Comment: have you tried this?

Comment: it doesn't work either. In fact the I tried putting it in my js file but it still doesnt work. Sam error